# Don't repeat element in ng-repeat scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

Is it possible to somehow define in angular, that I don't want to repeat some html tags inside `ng-repeat` scope. For e.g. I want to create a tab filter like this:

```
 <div class="searchandfilter" ng-app="phonecatApp">
    <span ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl"> 
        <span ng-repeat="phone in phones" class="tab-controller">
            <ul>
                <li class="tab" >{{phone.name}}</li>
            </ul>
            <span class="tab-content dont-repeat">
                <span>
                    <input type="checkbox">{{phone.brand}}</input>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I don't want to repeat span with class `dont-repeat`, but `span` with `input` inside I need to repeat.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzsetmeh/)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve here. Could you give us an example, with 3 or 4 phones, of what you want the generated HTML to look like? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be doable by just using `$first` in `ng-if` like `ng-if="$first"`

**Markup**

```
<span  ng-if="$first" class="tab-content dont-repeat">
    <span>
       <input type="checkbox">{{phone.brand}}</input>
    </span>
</span>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzsetmeh/1/)